# Accessing mapped object in AlamoFire framework returns nil value

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire, graphql

I am using a Swift Wrapper built on the Alamofire framework to return business data from Yelp via it's graphQL API. The call returns a JSON object which is then mapped into an object of type 'CDYelpBusiness' and I am able to access all of its properties save for hours, which is of type [CDYelpHour]?. It invariably returns nil and I'm sure that's due to a misunderstanding on my end, but I'm not sure what. Here is my call:

```
    yelpAPIClient.cancelAllPendingAPIRequests()
    yelpAPIClient.searchBusinesses(byTerm: "Martinis",
                                 location: nil,
                                 latitude: MapCenter.shared.latitude,
                                longitude: MapCenter.shared.longitude,
                                   radius: 16000,
                               categories: nil,
                                   locale: nil,
                                    limit: 20,
                                   offset: 0,
                                   sortBy: nil,
                               priceTiers: nil,
                                  openNow: false,
                                   openAt: nil,
                               attributes: nil) { (response) in

                                performUIUpdatesOnMain {

                                    if let response = response,
                                        let businesses = response.businesses,
                                        businesses.count > 0 {

                                        for business in businesses {
                                        Location.businesses.append(business)
                                            print(business.hours?[0].isOpenNow)

                                            let imageString = business.imageUrl?.absoluteString

                                            YelpClient.sharedInstance().loadImage(imageString, completionHandler: { (image) in
                                                Location.locationImages.append(image)
                                            })
                                        }

                                    }
```

This is the CDYelpBusiness object into which the response is mapped:

```
public class CDYelpBusiness: Mappable {

public var id: String?
public var name: String?
public var imageUrl: URL?
public var isClosed: Bool?
public var url: URL?
public var price: String?
public var phone: String?
public var displayPhone: String?
public var photos: [String]?
public var hours: [CDYelpHour]?
public var rating: Double?
public var reviewCount: Int?
public var categories: [CDYelpCategory]?
public var distance: Double?
public var coordinates: CDYelpCoordinates?
public var location: CDYelpLocation?
public var transactions: [String]?

public required init?(map: Map) {
}

public func mapping(map: Map) {
    id              <- map["id"]
    name            <- map["name"]
    imageUrl        <- (map["image_url"], URLTransform())
    isClosed        <- map["is_closed"]
    url             <- (map["url"], URLTransform())
    price           <- map["price"]
    phone           <- map["phone"]
    displayPhone    <- map["display_phone"]
    photos          <- map["photos"]
    hours           <- map["hours"]
    rating          <- map["rating"]
    reviewCount     <- map["review_count"]
    categories      <- map["categories"]
    distance        <- map["distance"]
    coordinates     <- map["coordinates"]
    location        <- map["location"]
    transactions    <- map["transactions"]
}
}
```

This is the CDYelpHour object:

```
public class CDYelpHour: Mappable {

public var hoursType: String?
public var open: [CDYelpOpen]?
public var isOpenNow: Bool?

public required init?(map: Map) {
}

public func mapping(map: Map) {
    hoursType   <- map["hours_type"]
    open        <- map["open"]
    isOpenNow   <- map["is_open_now"]
}
}
```

I can change my print statement inside of my for loop to extract other properties, by using, for example, business.id or business.name, but the attempt to get the hours property does not work.

I am trying to display whether the business "is open now". While the original network call has this as a parameter, it's only to filter the response for businesses that are currently open--when set to true. When set to false, as the default, it should return no filter on that parameter. Though that doesn't seem to be working either.

This is the framework:

https://github.com/chrisdhaan/CDYelpFusionKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let this be a lesson to myself to more thoroughly read the documentation.

The CDYelpFusionKit framework is designed for use with Yelp's RESTful API, and not the graphQL API for which it is possible to get a businesses opening hours in the original, single network call.

While the CDYelpBusiness class does include a variable for hours, those have to be retrieved in a separate network call.

Good times.